# jquery make sidebar dynamically filled (so with growing height) while scrolling positionned from top then from bottom

Tags: jquery, css, scroll, positioning

I have a sidebar dynamically filled with ajax (so with a growing height) while scrolling.

I've no problem to set the css and jquery when I want it to stay on top OR on bottom.

But what is the trick if I want the sidebar to stay on top when its height is less than the window height and then position it from the bottom when its height exceedss the window height?

Thank you very much for your attention, Eric

Answer (score 0):

You can get a divs height using the `.height()` function from jquery. See http://api.jquery.com/height/ for more info.

This way you could use:

```
if ($('#sidebar').height() > 400) {
    $('#sidebar').addClass('top');
} else {
    $('#sidebar').addClass('bottom');
}
```